# SVG transform and transition overlay with hover

Tags: svg, overlay, transform

I need each part of this svg map going on another one with hover. I mean when i going with mouse on each path of this , it's transform with transition and overlay on all of the other path.

now each path going under another path. i use z index and position relative and absolote in css but it's not working.
please help me , thanks

```
        <div class="map" id ="centermap">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 -21.6 761 919" style="enable-background:new 0 -21.6 761 919;" xml:space="preserve">
      <g   >
        <path class="st0" d="M208.4,244.3l-10.5,24.9l7.2,11.1l2.1,3.8l5.8,9.9l2.6,8l-4.8,13.4l7.2,20.3l-1,6.3l-1.6,6.2l3.7,11.8l7.5,12.2
l9.6,14.3l2.5,10.2l0,4.4l-10.9,0.7c-10,1.8-29.5,3.3-31.3,1.5c-0.2,0.7-6.4-1-6.2-1.7l-12.8-6.6l-5.9,1l-6.2-0.4l-7.6-2.6
l-12.5-5.9l-15.7-7.2l-35-19.9L77,353.7l-12.2-1.3l-15.1,2.1l-18.2,2l-8.3-1.3l-9.2-5.2l-6.8-6.7l-4.1-8.5V299h3.9l3.3,1.3l4.1,2.2
l6.2,4.3l3.3,3l4.2,1.3l4.3-1.3l4.3-2.8l7.7-0.9l10.2,0.3l1.7,0.4l3.1,3l0.8,1.3l1.3,1.2l2,1h4.2h4.6h2.9l5.4-1.6l6.8-3.3l8.5-6.3
l5.6-5l3.8-1.6l5-0.9h4.2l3.9,0.9l2.6,1l3,2.5l3.5,1.4l5.4,0.9l6.6,0.4h13.4l8.9-1.3l4.9-1.7l5.5-0.9l7.9-0.7l9.2-2.6l4.6-5.4
l-1.3-6.8l-4.2-8.1l2.6-10.6l-0.9-6.6l-1.3-4.6l0.7-3.8l3.5-2.8l5.2-1.6l4.2-4.6l1.7-5.2v-7.5l2-3.3l3.3-1.4h3.6l-0.9,2.8v3.1
l-1,9.2L208.4,244.3"/>    
           </g>
        <g   id="sar">
<path class="st0 " d="M239.7,401.4h-6.8l-10.5,0.9l-15.1,0.9h-10.6l-5.5-0.9l-5.6-2.8l-4.5-2.2l-4.7-2.4l-6.9,0.9l-5.1-0.3l-6.2-2.2
l-31.6-14.7l-33-18.8l-15.6-5.6l-14-2l-19,2.6l-14.3,1.4l-4.7-0.7l12.1,6.2l9.4,7.2l23.5,23.3l14.3,10.8l21.6,9.3l14.3,5.8
l23.3,13.2l31.2,15.7l14,5.8l10.5,3.8l11.8,2l12.3,4.2h4.6l2.6-8.3l5.6-12.2l3.8-7.5C244,435,242.8,401.3,239.7,401.4z"/>
</g>
       <g   id="sar">
       <path class="st0 " d="M214.2,250.2c0.3,0.2-7.6,17.5-7.4,17.6c0.6,3.9,1.1,7.9,4.9,9.8c2.8,1.4,6.2,1.9,9.3,2.3
c5.1,0.7,10.3,1,15.4,1.2c0.3-1.5,0.6-3.1,1-4.6c0.2-0.9,0.6-2.2,1.5-2.6c1-0.4,1.4,1.4,1.7,2c0.7,1.5,1.5,2.7,3,3.3
c0.6,0.2,2.3,0.9,2.7,0.2c0.4-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.1-1.9c0.7-1.2,1.4-2.3,2.1-3.5l2.7-4.4c3.4-0.6,4,4,5,6.3c0.5,1.1,0.8,2.4,1.9,3
c0.7,0.3,1.4,0.7,2.1,1l6.7,1.2l5.1,1.1l6.7-5.2l6.6-3.2c2.3-4.2,4.7-8.4,7-12.5c0.3-0.6,1.5-0.9,2.1-0.8c0.7,0,1.2,0.6,1.3,1.2
c0.4,1.7,0.3,3.8,0.1,5.5c-0.2,1.8-0.5,3.6-0.7,5.4c0,4.1-2.4,8.9-2.4,13.1c1,0.2-1.2,18.2-2.2,18l-2,18.4
c-1.4,6.2-2.9,12.6-3.6,18.9c-0.7,6.2,1.2,12.2,1.5,18.3c0,0.2,2.1,25.5,0.9,25.6l1.1,14.7l-0.3,9.8l1,10.2l-1.1,4.3
c0,0-43.7,6.6-46.1,3.4c-2.4-3.3-4.9-32.7-6.8-40.9c-9.5-11.4-15.4-22.7-19.3-34.1l-1.7-6.8l2.2-5.5l-1.4-10l-3.7-11l-1.6-5l1.9-5.1
c0.5-1.3,1-2.5,1.4-3.8c0-1.7,1-3.2,1.2-4.8c0.3-1.8-0.6-3.9-1.3-5.5c-0.8-2.1-1.5-4.2-2.9-6c-1.9-2.6-3.8-5.3-5.8-7.9l-3.5-4.9
c0,0-5-5.1-3.8-8.7c0.5,0.3,13.8-29.6,13.2-29.9c0-8.1,1.9-14.8,2.2-14.8c1.4,0,4.8-0.1,5.9,1.4c0.5,0.7,1.3,9.1,0.9,13
C220,238.1,215.5,246.3,214.2,250.2z"/>
</g>
      <g   id="sar">
      <path class="st0" d="M229.6,463.7c0-1,0-2,0-3c0-0.5-0.1-1.1,0-1.6c0.2-1,0.7-1.9,1.1-2.8c1-2.2,2.1-4.5,3.1-6.7
c1.6-3.5,3.2-7,4.8-10.5c0.9-1.8,1.9-3.6,2.6-5.5c0.8-2.1,1.6-4.2,2.3-6.4c4,0.6,8,1.1,12.1,0.8c4.7-0.4,9.4-0.8,14.1-1.4
c5.6-0.7,11.1-1.7,16.7-2.7l7.6-0.8c0,0,18.1-0.8,18.1-0.7c-0.2,4.1-0.3,8.3-0.7,12.4c-0.3,2.6-0.6,5.2-0.9,7.8
c-0.3,2.3-0.2,4.7-0.3,7c-0.2,4.4,0.4,8.8,0.7,13.2c0,0.6-0.2,1.3-0.3,1.9c-0.3,1.5-0.6,3.1-0.9,4.6c-0.1,0.6-0.1,1.5-0.5,2.1
c-0.7,1.2-1.3,2.3-2,3.5c-0.3,0.5-0.8,2.1-1.4,2.2c-1.2,0.2-2.5,0.4-3.7,0.6c-0.5,0.1-1,0.2-1.5,0.3c-0.4,0.1-1.1,0.3-1.5,0.3
c-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.2-2.1-0.3c-3-0.5-6.1-0.9-9.1-1.4c-1.3-0.2-2.7-0.4-4-0.7c-2.8-0.8-5.6-1.6-8.4-2.5c-3.8-1.1-7.7-2.2-11.6-3.3
c-4-1.1-8-2.3-12-3.1c-4.1-0.8-8.1-1.7-12.2-2.5c-1.7-0.3-3.5-0.3-5.1-0.5C232.9,463.9,231.2,463.9,229.6,463.7z"/>
        </g>
        <g   id="sar">
         <path class="st0" d="M302.3,479.4c2.5,9.4,4.9,18.8,7.4,28.3c1.1,4.1,2.1,8.2,3.2,12.2c0.2,0.7-0.8,1.1-1.2,1.6
c-1.9,1.7-3.8,3.5-5.6,5.2c-4.3,3.9-8.5,7.8-12.8,11.8c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.7-1.2,1.1c-0.5,0.5-0.8,1.7-1,2.3c-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.6-1.3,2.3
c-1.1,1-2.1,2-3.2,3c-1.2,1.2-2.8,2-4.2,2.9c-2.5,1.7-5,3.3-7.5,5c-1.2,0.8-2,1.6-3.1,2.6c-2.2,2.1-4.3,4.3-6.5,6.4
c-1,1-1.7,2-2.6,3.2c-1.7,2.5-3.5,5-5.2,7.5c-2.5,3.6-5.5,6.8-8.3,10.1c-1.2,1.4-2.8,2.5-4.2,3.7c-1.5,1.3-3.1,2.6-4.5,3.9
c-0.7,0.6-2,2.1-3.1,1.9c-0.9-0.2-0.6-3.1-0.6-3.7c-0.2-3-0.4-6.1-0.7-9.1c-0.1-1.5-0.1-3-0.2-4.5c-0.2-4-0.4-8-0.6-12
c-0.6-12.2-1.1-24.4-1.7-36.6c-0.6-12.1-1.1-24.3-1.7-36.5c-0.2-3.9-0.4-7.9-0.5-11.8c0-1.1-0.1-2.1-0.1-3.2c0-0.3,0-0.8-0.1-1.1
c-0.9-2.6-1.7-5.2-2.6-7.9c-0.3-1-0.7-2-1-3c-0.1-0.3-0.6-0.6-0.8-0.8c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.9-1.3-1.3c4.9,0.6,9.8,1.2,14.7,1.8
c4.3,0.5,8.5,1.6,12.7,2.4c7.2,1.5,14.4,3.5,21.6,5.3C283.8,474.9,293.1,477.1,302.3,479.4z"/>
</g>
        </svg>
       </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kav3/wwLfo49n/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`z-index` is an HTML property. It does not work in SVGs.  The order of elements is determined solely by their position in the file.

You will need to use javascript to move the path (you are hovering over) to the top.

```
var  mysvg = document.getElementById("Livello_1");

var  regions = mysvg.getElementsByTagName("path");
for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
    regions[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
        // Move the path to the top
        evt.target.parentNode.appendChild(evt.target);
        evt.target.classList.add("regionhover");
    });
    regions[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
        // Remove the hover class from the region
        evt.target.classList.remove("regionhover");
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wwLfo49n/2/

Note that I've changed the SVG a little also.  I put the paths all in one group so they have the same parent.  That is to make the `appendChild()` work.