# Unable to scale the polygon on hover

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to zoom (scale) the svg shape when i mouse over the polygon.
The effect i am looking is that the shape scale in Z direction. Here is what i have
tried.

```css
.hex{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hex:hover > * {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transform: scaleZ(5);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <g id="pod">
              <polygon stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width=".5" points="6,-15 -6,-15 -12,0 -6,15 6,15 12,0" />
            </g>
        </defs>
    <g class="hex">
                <use xlink:href="#pod" x="50" y="41" fill="#96ddff"/>
                <image xlink:href="https://placeholder.pics/svg/12" x="44" y="35" width="12" height="12"/>
        </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I take it you may have multiple shapes in your final svg. SVG inner elements are always positioned absolutely to svg viewbox dimensions settings. It's an interesting one this. You simple want a grow/genie effect on your hex element when hovered? It does seem like `transform-origin` and `translate` css goes out the window in this situation. 

Comment: Have you set up transform-perspective and transform-style preserve-3d somewhere - so the system knows you are wanting to scale in 3d. Even so,, just scaleZ will not do anything because there is no Z distance to scale. You can ask it to translateZ on a hover, to bring the polygon closer to the viewer, or further away, and if you want to augment the effect of that you can use scaleZ as well.

Comment: @AHaworth See fiddle with perspective and transform style css https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/awbjqyho/

Comment: Nothing has changed, apart from the scaleZ but that doesn't do anything since there is no movement along the Z axis to scale. The polygon has to move either towards or away from the viewer on the Z axis. I've put a snippet in an answer.

Comment: I was misleading about the need for preserving 3d as you aren't trying to move a 3d object. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply 3D transforms to `<svg>` elements that are on an HTML page, like you can for other (HTML) elements.

However 3D transforms on SVG *content* is not well supported by browsers as yet.

You don't exactly say what you are trying to achieve.  But am I right in guessing that you are actually wanting to enlarge the shape, as if it is coming closer to the camera?

If so, then you can just scale it around its centre.

```css
.hex {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.hex:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <g id="pod">
      <polygon stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width=".5" points="6,-15 -6,-15 -12,0 -6,15 6,15 12,0" />
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g class="hex">
    <use xlink:href="#pod" x="50" y="41" fill="#96ddff"/>
    <image xlink:href="https://placeholder.pics/svg/12" x="44" y="35" width="12" height="12"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Neat solution given some browsers apparently don't support 3D transforms which I didn't know - thanks for the info.

Comment: There is only one issue. I should have explained more, in my case i have multiple shapes layered out one next to another, with this solution whenever i mouse over on one shape it gets closer to the viewer but doesn't appear on top of other shapes, i tried to change the z-index but no effect.

Comment: @Xris SVG doesn't have z-index, you'd need to reorder the shapes.

Comment: I tried to reorder the shapes but there is always one shape that appears in the background of the other shapes whenever i mouse over it.

Comment: Robert means that you will need to move (ie using JS) the element you are hovering over, to the top. Top means "after all the other elements", since they are drawn in order.  Add a mouseenter event to those elements, and inside do something like `event.target.parentElement.appendChild(event.target)` or `event.target.ownerSVGElement.appendChild(event.target)`. What these do is move the hovered element to the end of the group or SVG, respectively.  See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368255/svg-transform-and-transition-overlay-with-hover

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this gives a 3D-based solution which worked for me (Edge on Windows10) but I've just learned that some browsers do not support that on svg content so as of November 2020 it is probably better to use a 2D solution.

To see a change on hover something has to change. Changing scaleZ does nothing because there is no Z dimension to scale - the polygon is flat

If you move it on hover - along the Z axis - with a positive distance towards the viewer then it will seem to get bigger (the polygon has only x and y dimensions, it is flat, so the scaleZ has no affect on its size in that sense).

Here is a snippet demonstrating the polygon getting larger on hover using the code in the initial question:

```css
.hex{
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateZ(0px);/* the initial position */
}

.hex:hover {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: perspective(500px) translateZ(50px);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <g id="pod">
              <polygon stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width=".5" points="6,-15 -6,-15 -12,0 -6,15 6,15 12,0" />
            </g>
        </defs>
    <g class="hex">
                <use xlink:href="#pod" x="50" y="41" fill="#96ddff"/>
                <image xlink:href="https://placeholder.pics/svg/12" x="44" y="35" width="12" height="12"/>
        </g>
</svg>
```