# Scaling paths within SVG overlapping

Tags: html, css, svg, path

I'm trying to create a responsive map only using CSS, but when the path scales on hover they overlap, is it possible to have it placed on top when hovering?

I've read that there is no use for z.indexing within the svg but I want to know if there's a better way for this approach,

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
}

.mapdiv path {
    fill: rgb(96, 84, 84);
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    stroke-width: 0.75;
    stroke-miterlimit: 4;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
    stroke-dasharray: none;
    display: inline;
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}

path:hover {
    fill: rgb(96, 0, 100);
    transform: scale(2);
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="mapdiv">
    <svg width="100%" viewBox="500 300 1000 650" id="svg2" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="layer4">
            <g id="Mexico">
                <path class="uno" d="M821.9 501c-1 .8-1.7 1-2.7 1.8-1 .9-1.2 1.1-2.6 1.2a12 12 0 00-4.2 1.6c-.6.3-.9 1-1 1.6-.4 1 7-1.2 7.4-1.6 1.2-1 2.6-.7 3.7-2 .3-.4.5-1.8-.6-2.6zm-18-44.4c-.1-.3 0-.7-.3-1h-.4s0-.3-.2-.2l-.2.2v.6c0 .1-.3 0-.4.4 0 .2.1.7 0 .8-.1.4-.9 0-.6.6.2.3.5.3.6.5.2.1-.1.2.4.2.2 0 .1-.2.2-.2.3-.1.9 0 .9-.2v-.3h.2c.1 0 .2-.3-.2-1.4zM791.5 433l.6-1c.2-.4-.3-.3-.4-.3h-1c-.6 0 .2-.6-.2-.4l-.4.6v.6c0 .2 0 .3.2.3h.2c.2 0-.2.2.4.2h.6zm102.6 97v-52.4l-15.3-16.8-.6-10.1-2.4.6-1.5 2-2.7-3.2H870l-.6-5.7-10.5.6v-4.2l-3.9-.3h-2.4l-.6-10.5-2-.1a56.9 56.9 0 00-2.5 17.5c0 2.8 3.3 6.3 3 10.8-.1 2.3-3.4 7.9-4.4 10.3-3.4 7.8-.1 12.6-6.6 17.8-3.6 3-11.6 12.5-16 12.9.5 1.2.2 1.6 1.2 1.6s1.8-.5 2.4-.5c.5 0 .5 1.3.7 1.7.6 1 5 .7 6 .7-2.4 0-6.5 0-4.6 4h2.1c1.8 0-2.2.4-2.6.4-.9.1-1.9 3.8-3.7 3-4.4-1.7-2.4 4.6-6.3 4-.5 0-1.8-1.3-2.9-.7-1 .7-.7 3.3-1.6 3.3h-2.8c-1.7 0-1.3.2-1.4-1.4 0-.8-.4-.6 1-.7 0 0 1.5.2 1.1-.4-.4-.6-1-.9-1-1.7 0-2.3-1 .8-1.8-.5-1.6-2.4-2.1 1-3.8 0-.7-.4 0 0-1.1-.4-.3-.1-1-1.2-1.2-1.2-1.3-.1-1.1.5-1.6 1.2-.5 0-2.5.5-3 .2-.9-.3-1.2-.5-.3-.7.4-.1 1.2 0 1.6 0 .5 0 1.4.3 1.2-.5-.2-.5-.4-.8-.5-1.4 0-.5 0-.5.3-.7 1.7 0 3.3 0 4.9.5.7.3 1.4-.7 2.5-.7.6 0 1.3-.6.7-1.2-.5-.5-3.3-.4-4.2-1.1-1.7-1.4-4.6.6-6 1.4-1 .5-3.5 0-4.7.4-1.5.5-2.6.3-3.6.6v1.4l2.8.7v3l1.7-.3.4 1.2c0 .4 1.6.2 2 .2h.6c.4 0 1.5-1 1.6-.4.2 1 .6 0 1.3.4.2.2-.3.2.4.2h1v7.5c1.4.2.8 3.9 1.8 3.9s1.5.1 2-.4 3.4 1.6 4 1.8c.4.1 1.6-.1 2 .2.6 1-1 1.8.7 1.8.9 0 3.6 0 4 .7 1 1 2.3 1.2 4 1.2v-7.6h3c1.3 0 2.2 1 3.6 1.5 2.4.7 2.5-.8 4.7 1 1.9 1.5 6.1-.4 8.5 1.7v4.3c18.8 0 34.8-1 53.4-2.4z" id="CAM"/>
                <path d="M745.7 598l-.2-2.3c0-1.4.7-1.2.7-2.3 0-1.7-.4-1.5 1.3-1.6.6 0 .3-1.9.3-2.6V586c0-2-1.9-2.1-4.2-2.3l7.1-21.9c.8-.3 1.6-.3 2-.8.5-.5-.6-1.4.3-2.3.9-.8 3.2 0 3.6-1l.2-1c.9-1.8 2.4 1.2 2.7-2.6 0-1.4 1.3-.9 1.6-1.5a26 26 0 001.2-4c.3-1.5.6-.8 1.2-1.5.9-.8-.3-1.4 1-2.4.4-.3 1-.5 1.3-1 1.1-1.3 1-3.2-1.2-3.2l-.2-3.2 1-3.7c1.4-.6 1.4.4 1.8-.7.2-.4.8-.2 1-.3.5-.3 1.1-.1 1.8-.2.4 0 0-.7.7-.7.6 0 2.4.8 1.2 1.4-.2.1-1-.3-.7.3.4 1 .5.3 1 1 .3 0 .5.8.6.8.5 0 1-.4 1.6-.4.8 0 .5.7.5 1.4 0 .6.4.9 0 1.4-.4.7 1.4.7 1.6.8v6.3c.5 0 1.4.7 1.4 1.2 0 1.4-.4 1.6 1.2 1.6l2.5-.2c2.4 0 .9 0 2 1.2.1.2.4.1.3.4-.2.3-1.3 2.2-.2 1.9.3 0 1.5-.1 1.6.2 0 .7-.9.7-.4 1 1.2.7.7.7 2.3.7.1-.3.4 0 .5-.5.1-.3.3-.6.2-1 0-.5-.1 0-.2-.4 0-.6.6-1.7 1-2 .3 0 .5 0 .6-.3.2-.3 0-1.8.2-2.3.6 0 2.6 0 2.6-.7 0-1.2.6-1 1.6-1.4 2-.7 3.4.4 4.4-2 .6-1.5-1-2.3 1.4-2.3.8 0-1 .8.2-.6.4-.6 1.5-.6 1.9-1 .8-1 3.1-1.7 3.1-2.7 0-1 0-.9 1.1-1.2.8-.2 1.8 0 1.8-1.2 0-1.4.8-3.8 1.5-1.4.2.6.6 0 .6 1 0 1.5 1.1 1 1.2.4 0-1 0-.7 1-.7s1.2.4 2.1.7c.4.1 1 .2 1.1.5.2.7 0 1.2.3 1.8.5.6 0 1-.1 1.7.3.3.3.7.5.7.5 0 .5 0 .9.4.9.7.4.3 1.4.2 1.3-.2.8 0 1 1 .2 1 .6-.5.6.9 0 1.3 1 .2 1.2 1.4 0 .8-.9 1.3-.4 2 .3.2.3 1 0 1.1-.5.5-1.2.5-.5 1 .2 0 .2.6.2 1-.6.2 0 .8.7.5.4-.2.7-.4 1.6-.4 1.3 0 .9 1 1.7 1 .4 0 2.2-.3 2.3 0 0 .7.3 2.5 1 1 .5-.9.4-.7.8-.4.2.3.8.2.8.7 0 1.3-.7.5-.7 1.8 0 .5-.2 1.3-.1 1.6 0 .5 1.3-.2 1.7.4h-1c.5.8.6 1 1.3 1.3l.3.1c.7.3.1.4.5 1 .3.4.6.7 1 .7s1 0 1.1.2c.3.2 1 .2 1 .8.2.6.1.9.7 1.1 1 .4 1.6-.2 1.6 1 0 1.3 1.2.8 1.3 2.2 0 .6 4.2-.7 3.2.8-.3.4-.5-.2-.4.7 0 .8 1 2.1 1.6 2.1.7 0 1.1-.4 1.9-.4 0 2.4.5 2 2.6 2 2.7 0 6.1 2.8 6.3 5.2 0 .7.8 2.7 1.2 2.8 2 .4 1.3 3.9 3.6 3.2 1.4-.4 1.8-.9 3 .4l1 1c.3.1 1.2-.3 1.7-.3v1.7c0 1-1 .1-1 1-.2 1.1-1.2 1.8-1 3 .3 1 .7 5.3 1.5 5.6l-40.6 1.8-15.2 29.7 4.7 3.9c0 4.3-2 6.9-2 11 0 1.9-.6 2.6-.6 4.4 0 2-1 2.7-1.8 3.7a70 70 0 01-8.1-7.4c-7.5-10.8-20.1-16.9-30-26.1-4.6-4.3-12.8-6.6-17.8-10.9a13.8 13.8 0 00-6-2.3z" id="CHP"/>
                <path d="M740.8 526.8l1.3 2.3.2 3.3c0 1.6.5.6 1 1.6.2.4-1.5 2.2-.5 3.5.3.4 2.6-.2 3 0 1.6 1-.8 1.5 2.1 2.6 1.3 1 1.6 2.7 3.3 2.8 1.6 0 4 1 3.6 2.5-.5 1.8 2 1.6 2.3 2.3 0 .1.5 4.5-.3 4.9-1.3.7 0 2.2 0 4 .9-1.7 2.4 1.3 2.7-2.5 0-1.4 1.3-.9 1.6-1.5a26 26 0 001.2-4c.3-1.5.6-.8 1.2-1.5.9-.8-.3-1.4 1-2.4.4-.3 1-.5 1.3-1 1.1-1.3 1-3.2-1.2-3.2l-.2-3.2 1-3.7c1.4-.6 1.4.4 1.8-.7.2-.4.8-.2 1-.3.5-.3 1.1-.1 1.8-.2.4 0 0-.7.7-.7.6 0 2.4.8 1.2 1.4-.2.1-1-.3-.7.3.4 1 .5.3 1 1 .3 0 .5.8.6.8.5 0 1-.4 1.6-.4.8 0 .5.7.5 1.4 0 .6.4.9 0 1.4-.4.7 1.4.7 1.6.8v6.3c.5 0 1.4.7 1.4 1.2 0 1.4-.4 1.6 1.2 1.6l2.5-.2c2.4 0 .9 0 2 1.2.1.2.4.1.3.4-.2.3-1.3 2.2-.2 1.9.3 0 1.5-.1 1.6.2 0 .7-.9.7-.4 1 1.2.7.7.7 2.3.7.1-.3.4 0 .5-.5.1-.3.3-.6.2-1 0-.5-.1 0-.2-.4 0-.6.6-1.7 1-2 .3 0 .5 0 .6-.3.2-.3 0-1.8.2-2.3.6 0 2.6 0 2.6-.7 0-1.2.6-1 1.6-1.4 2-.7 3.4.4 4.4-2 .6-1.5-1-2.3 1.4-2.3.8 0-1 .8.2-.6.4-.6 1.5-.6 1.9-1 .8-1 3.1-1.7 3.1-2.7 0-1 0-.9 1.1-1.2.8-.2 1.8 0 1.8-1.2 0-1.4.8-3.8 1.5-1.4.2.6.6 0 .6 1 0 1.5 1.1 1 1.2.4 0-1 0-.7 1-.7s1.2.4 2.1.7c.4.1 1 .2 1.1.5.2.7 0 1.2.3 1.8.5.6 0 1-.1 1.7.3.3.3.7.5.7.5 0 .5 0 .9.4.9.7.4.3 1.4.2 1.3-.2.8 0 1 1 .2 1 .6-.5.6.9 0 1.3 1 .2 1.2 1.4 0 .8-.9 1.3-.4 2 .3.2.3 1 0 1.1-.5.5-1.2.5-.5 1 .2 0 .2.6.2 1-.6.2 0 .8.7.5.4-.2.7-.4 1.6-.4 1.3 0 .9 1 1.7 1 .4 0 2.2-.3 2.3 0 0 .7.3 2.5 1 1 .5-.9.4-.7.8-.4.2.3.8.2.8.7 0 1.3-.7.5-.7 1.8 0 .5-.2 1.3-.1 1.6 0 .5 1.3-.2 1.7.4l11-.2-.2-7-.1-17.7c-2.4-2-6.6-.2-8.5-1.7-2.2-1.8-2.3-.3-4.7-1-1.4-.4-2.3-1.4-3.6-1.4h-3v7.5c-1.7 0-3-.1-4-1.2-.4-.7-3.1-.7-4-.7-1.8 0 0-.9-.8-1.8-.3-.3-1.5 0-1.8-.2-.7-.2-3.6-2.3-4-1.8-.6.5-1 .4-2.1.4-1 0-.4-3.7-1.8-3.9v-7.5h-1c-.7 0-.2 0-.4-.2-.7-.3-1 .6-1.3-.4 0-.6-1.2.4-1.6.4h-.6c-.4 0-2 .2-2-.2l-.4-1.2-1.7.2v-2.9l-2.8-.7v-1.4c-.4.1-.9.4-1.4.8-1.8.7-3.1 1.3-4.6 2.1-1.1.6-1.9.5-2.9 1.4-2 2.1-5 4.6-8 4.7-.8 0-1.4.2-1.3 1.2 0 1.2-.9 4-2.6 2.8-2-1.4 2.3-2.8 1.2-2.8-.9 0-2.3.3-2.4.2-.6-.6-2.5-.7-3.7-.7-2.2 0-6 0-7 1.2-3.5 3.6-10.5 2-13 5.9l-2.3.7c-.7.2-1.3.5-1.8.9z" id="TAB"/>
            </g>
            <g id="g6310" transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,1636.39,215.04306)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael said already, `z-index` does not currently work for SVGs.

You will need to use JS events to catch hovers over your map paths, then move the hovered path to the bottom of the document.  Since it will get drawn last, it appears to be front of the other paths.

I already have an answer that show how to do that here:

[SVG transform and transition overlay with hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368255/svg-transform-and-transition-overlay-with-hover)

Whether that works exactly how you want will depend on the structure of your SVG.  Instead of moving just the path (as that code does), you may want to move the whole region/country.  That would mean moving the `<g>` parent element, instead of just the `<path>`.

Anyway, here is code to do the equivalent of what you had in your question.

```js
var  mysvg = document.getElementById("svg2");

var  regions = mysvg.querySelectorAll("path");
regions.forEach(reg => {

  reg.addEventListener("mouseover", evt => {
    // When the mouse starts hovering over a path, move the path to the front.
    // appendChild() appends an element (the path) to children of a parent element.
    // It will get added to the end of the parent element's list of
    // children. But since, in this case, it is already a child of that
    // parent, it simply gets moved to the end.
    evt.target.parentNode.appendChild(evt.target);
    // Give it the "hover" class
    evt.target.classList.add("hover");
  });

  reg.addEventListener("mouseout", evt => {
    // When mouse leave path, remove the hover class from it
    evt.target.classList.remove("hover");
  });

});
```

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
}

.mapdiv path {
    fill: rgb(96, 84, 84);
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    stroke-width: 0.75;
    stroke-miterlimit: 4;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
    stroke-dasharray: none;
    display: inline;
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}

path.hover {
    fill: rgb(96, 0, 100);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="mapdiv">
    <svg width="100%" viewBox="500 300 1000 650" id="svg2" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="layer4">
            <g id="Mexico">
                <path class="uno" d="M821.9 501c-1 .8-1.7 1-2.7 1.8-1 .9-1.2 1.1-2.6 1.2a12 12 0 00-4.2 1.6c-.6.3-.9 1-1 1.6-.4 1 7-1.2 7.4-1.6 1.2-1 2.6-.7 3.7-2 .3-.4.5-1.8-.6-2.6zm-18-44.4c-.1-.3 0-.7-.3-1h-.4s0-.3-.2-.2l-.2.2v.6c0 .1-.3 0-.4.4 0 .2.1.7 0 .8-.1.4-.9 0-.6.6.2.3.5.3.6.5.2.1-.1.2.4.2.2 0 .1-.2.2-.2.3-.1.9 0 .9-.2v-.3h.2c.1 0 .2-.3-.2-1.4zM791.5 433l.6-1c.2-.4-.3-.3-.4-.3h-1c-.6 0 .2-.6-.2-.4l-.4.6v.6c0 .2 0 .3.2.3h.2c.2 0-.2.2.4.2h.6zm102.6 97v-52.4l-15.3-16.8-.6-10.1-2.4.6-1.5 2-2.7-3.2H870l-.6-5.7-10.5.6v-4.2l-3.9-.3h-2.4l-.6-10.5-2-.1a56.9 56.9 0 00-2.5 17.5c0 2.8 3.3 6.3 3 10.8-.1 2.3-3.4 7.9-4.4 10.3-3.4 7.8-.1 12.6-6.6 17.8-3.6 3-11.6 12.5-16 12.9.5 1.2.2 1.6 1.2 1.6s1.8-.5 2.4-.5c.5 0 .5 1.3.7 1.7.6 1 5 .7 6 .7-2.4 0-6.5 0-4.6 4h2.1c1.8 0-2.2.4-2.6.4-.9.1-1.9 3.8-3.7 3-4.4-1.7-2.4 4.6-6.3 4-.5 0-1.8-1.3-2.9-.7-1 .7-.7 3.3-1.6 3.3h-2.8c-1.7 0-1.3.2-1.4-1.4 0-.8-.4-.6 1-.7 0 0 1.5.2 1.1-.4-.4-.6-1-.9-1-1.7 0-2.3-1 .8-1.8-.5-1.6-2.4-2.1 1-3.8 0-.7-.4 0 0-1.1-.4-.3-.1-1-1.2-1.2-1.2-1.3-.1-1.1.5-1.6 1.2-.5 0-2.5.5-3 .2-.9-.3-1.2-.5-.3-.7.4-.1 1.2 0 1.6 0 .5 0 1.4.3 1.2-.5-.2-.5-.4-.8-.5-1.4 0-.5 0-.5.3-.7 1.7 0 3.3 0 4.9.5.7.3 1.4-.7 2.5-.7.6 0 1.3-.6.7-1.2-.5-.5-3.3-.4-4.2-1.1-1.7-1.4-4.6.6-6 1.4-1 .5-3.5 0-4.7.4-1.5.5-2.6.3-3.6.6v1.4l2.8.7v3l1.7-.3.4 1.2c0 .4 1.6.2 2 .2h.6c.4 0 1.5-1 1.6-.4.2 1 .6 0 1.3.4.2.2-.3.2.4.2h1v7.5c1.4.2.8 3.9 1.8 3.9s1.5.1 2-.4 3.4 1.6 4 1.8c.4.1 1.6-.1 2 .2.6 1-1 1.8.7 1.8.9 0 3.6 0 4 .7 1 1 2.3 1.2 4 1.2v-7.6h3c1.3 0 2.2 1 3.6 1.5 2.4.7 2.5-.8 4.7 1 1.9 1.5 6.1-.4 8.5 1.7v4.3c18.8 0 34.8-1 53.4-2.4z" id="CAM"/>
                <path d="M745.7 598l-.2-2.3c0-1.4.7-1.2.7-2.3 0-1.7-.4-1.5 1.3-1.6.6 0 .3-1.9.3-2.6V586c0-2-1.9-2.1-4.2-2.3l7.1-21.9c.8-.3 1.6-.3 2-.8.5-.5-.6-1.4.3-2.3.9-.8 3.2 0 3.6-1l.2-1c.9-1.8 2.4 1.2 2.7-2.6 0-1.4 1.3-.9 1.6-1.5a26 26 0 001.2-4c.3-1.5.6-.8 1.2-1.5.9-.8-.3-1.4 1-2.4.4-.3 1-.5 1.3-1 1.1-1.3 1-3.2-1.2-3.2l-.2-3.2 1-3.7c1.4-.6 1.4.4 1.8-.7.2-.4.8-.2 1-.3.5-.3 1.1-.1 1.8-.2.4 0 0-.7.7-.7.6 0 2.4.8 1.2 1.4-.2.1-1-.3-.7.3.4 1 .5.3 1 1 .3 0 .5.8.6.8.5 0 1-.4 1.6-.4.8 0 .5.7.5 1.4 0 .6.4.9 0 1.4-.4.7 1.4.7 1.6.8v6.3c.5 0 1.4.7 1.4 1.2 0 1.4-.4 1.6 1.2 1.6l2.5-.2c2.4 0 .9 0 2 1.2.1.2.4.1.3.4-.2.3-1.3 2.2-.2 1.9.3 0 1.5-.1 1.6.2 0 .7-.9.7-.4 1 1.2.7.7.7 2.3.7.1-.3.4 0 .5-.5.1-.3.3-.6.2-1 0-.5-.1 0-.2-.4 0-.6.6-1.7 1-2 .3 0 .5 0 .6-.3.2-.3 0-1.8.2-2.3.6 0 2.6 0 2.6-.7 0-1.2.6-1 1.6-1.4 2-.7 3.4.4 4.4-2 .6-1.5-1-2.3 1.4-2.3.8 0-1 .8.2-.6.4-.6 1.5-.6 1.9-1 .8-1 3.1-1.7 3.1-2.7 0-1 0-.9 1.1-1.2.8-.2 1.8 0 1.8-1.2 0-1.4.8-3.8 1.5-1.4.2.6.6 0 .6 1 0 1.5 1.1 1 1.2.4 0-1 0-.7 1-.7s1.2.4 2.1.7c.4.1 1 .2 1.1.5.2.7 0 1.2.3 1.8.5.6 0 1-.1 1.7.3.3.3.7.5.7.5 0 .5 0 .9.4.9.7.4.3 1.4.2 1.3-.2.8 0 1 1 .2 1 .6-.5.6.9 0 1.3 1 .2 1.2 1.4 0 .8-.9 1.3-.4 2 .3.2.3 1 0 1.1-.5.5-1.2.5-.5 1 .2 0 .2.6.2 1-.6.2 0 .8.7.5.4-.2.7-.4 1.6-.4 1.3 0 .9 1 1.7 1 .4 0 2.2-.3 2.3 0 0 .7.3 2.5 1 1 .5-.9.4-.7.8-.4.2.3.8.2.8.7 0 1.3-.7.5-.7 1.8 0 .5-.2 1.3-.1 1.6 0 .5 1.3-.2 1.7.4h-1c.5.8.6 1 1.3 1.3l.3.1c.7.3.1.4.5 1 .3.4.6.7 1 .7s1 0 1.1.2c.3.2 1 .2 1 .8.2.6.1.9.7 1.1 1 .4 1.6-.2 1.6 1 0 1.3 1.2.8 1.3 2.2 0 .6 4.2-.7 3.2.8-.3.4-.5-.2-.4.7 0 .8 1 2.1 1.6 2.1.7 0 1.1-.4 1.9-.4 0 2.4.5 2 2.6 2 2.7 0 6.1 2.8 6.3 5.2 0 .7.8 2.7 1.2 2.8 2 .4 1.3 3.9 3.6 3.2 1.4-.4 1.8-.9 3 .4l1 1c.3.1 1.2-.3 1.7-.3v1.7c0 1-1 .1-1 1-.2 1.1-1.2 1.8-1 3 .3 1 .7 5.3 1.5 5.6l-40.6 1.8-15.2 29.7 4.7 3.9c0 4.3-2 6.9-2 11 0 1.9-.6 2.6-.6 4.4 0 2-1 2.7-1.8 3.7a70 70 0 01-8.1-7.4c-7.5-10.8-20.1-16.9-30-26.1-4.6-4.3-12.8-6.6-17.8-10.9a13.8 13.8 0 00-6-2.3z" id="CHP"/>
                <path d="M740.8 526.8l1.3 2.3.2 3.3c0 1.6.5.6 1 1.6.2.4-1.5 2.2-.5 3.5.3.4 2.6-.2 3 0 1.6 1-.8 1.5 2.1 2.6 1.3 1 1.6 2.7 3.3 2.8 1.6 0 4 1 3.6 2.5-.5 1.8 2 1.6 2.3 2.3 0 .1.5 4.5-.3 4.9-1.3.7 0 2.2 0 4 .9-1.7 2.4 1.3 2.7-2.5 0-1.4 1.3-.9 1.6-1.5a26 26 0 001.2-4c.3-1.5.6-.8 1.2-1.5.9-.8-.3-1.4 1-2.4.4-.3 1-.5 1.3-1 1.1-1.3 1-3.2-1.2-3.2l-.2-3.2 1-3.7c1.4-.6 1.4.4 1.8-.7.2-.4.8-.2 1-.3.5-.3 1.1-.1 1.8-.2.4 0 0-.7.7-.7.6 0 2.4.8 1.2 1.4-.2.1-1-.3-.7.3.4 1 .5.3 1 1 .3 0 .5.8.6.8.5 0 1-.4 1.6-.4.8 0 .5.7.5 1.4 0 .6.4.9 0 1.4-.4.7 1.4.7 1.6.8v6.3c.5 0 1.4.7 1.4 1.2 0 1.4-.4 1.6 1.2 1.6l2.5-.2c2.4 0 .9 0 2 1.2.1.2.4.1.3.4-.2.3-1.3 2.2-.2 1.9.3 0 1.5-.1 1.6.2 0 .7-.9.7-.4 1 1.2.7.7.7 2.3.7.1-.3.4 0 .5-.5.1-.3.3-.6.2-1 0-.5-.1 0-.2-.4 0-.6.6-1.7 1-2 .3 0 .5 0 .6-.3.2-.3 0-1.8.2-2.3.6 0 2.6 0 2.6-.7 0-1.2.6-1 1.6-1.4 2-.7 3.4.4 4.4-2 .6-1.5-1-2.3 1.4-2.3.8 0-1 .8.2-.6.4-.6 1.5-.6 1.9-1 .8-1 3.1-1.7 3.1-2.7 0-1 0-.9 1.1-1.2.8-.2 1.8 0 1.8-1.2 0-1.4.8-3.8 1.5-1.4.2.6.6 0 .6 1 0 1.5 1.1 1 1.2.4 0-1 0-.7 1-.7s1.2.4 2.1.7c.4.1 1 .2 1.1.5.2.7 0 1.2.3 1.8.5.6 0 1-.1 1.7.3.3.3.7.5.7.5 0 .5 0 .9.4.9.7.4.3 1.4.2 1.3-.2.8 0 1 1 .2 1 .6-.5.6.9 0 1.3 1 .2 1.2 1.4 0 .8-.9 1.3-.4 2 .3.2.3 1 0 1.1-.5.5-1.2.5-.5 1 .2 0 .2.6.2 1-.6.2 0 .8.7.5.4-.2.7-.4 1.6-.4 1.3 0 .9 1 1.7 1 .4 0 2.2-.3 2.3 0 0 .7.3 2.5 1 1 .5-.9.4-.7.8-.4.2.3.8.2.8.7 0 1.3-.7.5-.7 1.8 0 .5-.2 1.3-.1 1.6 0 .5 1.3-.2 1.7.4l11-.2-.2-7-.1-17.7c-2.4-2-6.6-.2-8.5-1.7-2.2-1.8-2.3-.3-4.7-1-1.4-.4-2.3-1.4-3.6-1.4h-3v7.5c-1.7 0-3-.1-4-1.2-.4-.7-3.1-.7-4-.7-1.8 0 0-.9-.8-1.8-.3-.3-1.5 0-1.8-.2-.7-.2-3.6-2.3-4-1.8-.6.5-1 .4-2.1.4-1 0-.4-3.7-1.8-3.9v-7.5h-1c-.7 0-.2 0-.4-.2-.7-.3-1 .6-1.3-.4 0-.6-1.2.4-1.6.4h-.6c-.4 0-2 .2-2-.2l-.4-1.2-1.7.2v-2.9l-2.8-.7v-1.4c-.4.1-.9.4-1.4.8-1.8.7-3.1 1.3-4.6 2.1-1.1.6-1.9.5-2.9 1.4-2 2.1-5 4.6-8 4.7-.8 0-1.4.2-1.3 1.2 0 1.2-.9 4-2.6 2.8-2-1.4 2.3-2.8 1.2-2.8-.9 0-2.3.3-2.4.2-.6-.6-2.5-.7-3.7-.7-2.2 0-6 0-7 1.2-3.5 3.6-10.5 2-13 5.9l-2.3.7c-.7.2-1.3.5-1.8.9z" id="TAB"/>
            </g>
            <g id="g6310" transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,1636.39,215.04306)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no z-index in SVG, you need to change the internal order of `<path>` elements within `<svg>`. You can do it with D3 `raise()` function:

```
 d3.selectAll('path')
   .on('mouseenter', e => d3.select(e.target).raise());
```

```js
d3.selectAll('path').on('mouseenter', (e) => d3.select(e.target).attr('fill', 'red').raise());
```

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
}

.mapdiv path {
    fill: rgb(96, 84, 84);
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    stroke-width: 0.75;
    stroke-miterlimit: 4;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
    stroke-dasharray: none;
    display: inline;
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}

path:hover {
    fill: rgb(96, 0, 100);
    transform: scale(2);
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="mapdiv">
    <svg width="100%" viewBox="500 300 1000 650" id="svg2" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="layer4">
            <g id="Mexico">
                <path class="uno" d="M821.9 501c-1 .8-1.7 1-2.7 1.8-1 .9-1.2 1.1-2.6 1.2a12 12 0 00-4.2 1.6c-.6.3-.9 1-1 1.6-.4 1 7-1.2 7.4-1.6 1.2-1 2.6-.7 3.7-2 .3-.4.5-1.8-.6-2.6zm-18-44.4c-.1-.3 0-.7-.3-1h-.4s0-.3-.2-.2l-.2.2v.6c0 .1-.3 0-.4.4 0 .2.1.7 0 .8-.1.4-.9 0-.6.6.2.3.5.3.6.5.2.1-.1.2.4.2.2 0 .1-.2.2-.2.3-.1.9 0 .9-.2v-.3h.2c.1 0 .2-.3-.2-1.4zM791.5 433l.6-1c.2-.4-.3-.3-.4-.3h-1c-.6 0 .2-.6-.2-.4l-.4.6v.6c0 .2 0 .3.2.3h.2c.2 0-.2.2.4.2h.6zm102.6 97v-52.4l-15.3-16.8-.6-10.1-2.4.6-1.5 2-2.7-3.2H870l-.6-5.7-10.5.6v-4.2l-3.9-.3h-2.4l-.6-10.5-2-.1a56.9 56.9 0 00-2.5 17.5c0 2.8 3.3 6.3 3 10.8-.1 2.3-3.4 7.9-4.4 10.3-3.4 7.8-.1 12.6-6.6 17.8-3.6 3-11.6 12.5-16 12.9.5 1.2.2 1.6 1.2 1.6s1.8-.5 2.4-.5c.5 0 .5 1.3.7 1.7.6 1 5 .7 6 .7-2.4 0-6.5 0-4.6 4h2.1c1.8 0-2.2.4-2.6.4-.9.1-1.9 3.8-3.7 3-4.4-1.7-2.4 4.6-6.3 4-.5 0-1.8-1.3-2.9-.7-1 .7-.7 3.3-1.6 3.3h-2.8c-1.7 0-1.3.2-1.4-1.4 0-.8-.4-.6 1-.7 0 0 1.5.2 1.1-.4-.4-.6-1-.9-1-1.7 0-2.3-1 .8-1.8-.5-1.6-2.4-2.1 1-3.8 0-.7-.4 0 0-1.1-.4-.3-.1-1-1.2-1.2-1.2-1.3-.1-1.1.5-1.6 1.2-.5 0-2.5.5-3 .2-.9-.3-1.2-.5-.3-.7.4-.1 1.2 0 1.6 0 .5 0 1.4.3 1.2-.5-.2-.5-.4-.8-.5-1.4 0-.5 0-.5.3-.7 1.7 0 3.3 0 4.9.5.7.3 1.4-.7 2.5-.7.6 0 1.3-.6.7-1.2-.5-.5-3.3-.4-4.2-1.1-1.7-1.4-4.6.6-6 1.4-1 .5-3.5 0-4.7.4-1.5.5-2.6.3-3.6.6v1.4l2.8.7v3l1.7-.3.4 1.2c0 .4 1.6.2 2 .2h.6c.4 0 1.5-1 1.6-.4.2 1 .6 0 1.3.4.2.2-.3.2.4.2h1v7.5c1.4.2.8 3.9 1.8 3.9s1.5.1 2-.4 3.4 1.6 4 1.8c.4.1 1.6-.1 2 .2.6 1-1 1.8.7 1.8.9 0 3.6 0 4 .7 1 1 2.3 1.2 4 1.2v-7.6h3c1.3 0 2.2 1 3.6 1.5 2.4.7 2.5-.8 4.7 1 1.9 1.5 6.1-.4 8.5 1.7v4.3c18.8 0 34.8-1 53.4-2.4z" id="CAM"/>
                <path d="M745.7 598l-.2-2.3c0-1.4.7-1.2.7-2.3 0-1.7-.4-1.5 1.3-1.6.6 0 .3-1.9.3-2.6V586c0-2-1.9-2.1-4.2-2.3l7.1-21.9c.8-.3 1.6-.3 2-.8.5-.5-.6-1.4.3-2.3.9-.8 3.2 0 3.6-1l.2-1c.9-1.8 2.4 1.2 2.7-2.6 0-1.4 1.3-.9 1.6-1.5a26 26 0 001.2-4c.3-1.5.6-.8 1.2-1.5.9-.8-.3-1.4 1-2.4.4-.3 1-.5 1.3-1 1.1-1.3 1-3.2-1.2-3.2l-.2-3.2 1-3.7c1.4-.6 1.4.4 1.8-.7.2-.4.8-.2 1-.3.5-.3 1.1-.1 1.8-.2.4 0 0-.7.7-.7.6 0 2.4.8 1.2 1.4-.2.1-1-.3-.7.3.4 1 .5.3 1 1 .3 0 .5.8.6.8.5 0 1-.4 1.6-.4.8 0 .5.7.5 1.4 0 .6.4.9 0 1.4-.4.7 1.4.7 1.6.8v6.3c.5 0 1.4.7 1.4 1.2 0 1.4-.4 1.6 1.2 1.6l2.5-.2c2.4 0 .9 0 2 1.2.1.2.4.1.3.4-.2.3-1.3 2.2-.2 1.9.3 0 1.5-.1 1.6.2 0 .7-.9.7-.4 1 1.2.7.7.7 2.3.7.1-.3.4 0 .5-.5.1-.3.3-.6.2-1 0-.5-.1 0-.2-.4 0-.6.6-1.7 1-2 .3 0 .5 0 .6-.3.2-.3 0-1.8.2-2.3.6 0 2.6 0 2.6-.7 0-1.2.6-1 1.6-1.4 2-.7 3.4.4 4.4-2 .6-1.5-1-2.3 1.4-2.3.8 0-1 .8.2-.6.4-.6 1.5-.6 1.9-1 .8-1 3.1-1.7 3.1-2.7 0-1 0-.9 1.1-1.2.8-.2 1.8 0 1.8-1.2 0-1.4.8-3.8 1.5-1.4.2.6.6 0 .6 1 0 1.5 1.1 1 1.2.4 0-1 0-.7 1-.7s1.2.4 2.1.7c.4.1 1 .2 1.1.5.2.7 0 1.2.3 1.8.5.6 0 1-.1 1.7.3.3.3.7.5.7.5 0 .5 0 .9.4.9.7.4.3 1.4.2 1.3-.2.8 0 1 1 .2 1 .6-.5.6.9 0 1.3 1 .2 1.2 1.4 0 .8-.9 1.3-.4 2 .3.2.3 1 0 1.1-.5.5-1.2.5-.5 1 .2 0 .2.6.2 1-.6.2 0 .8.7.5.4-.2.7-.4 1.6-.4 1.3 0 .9 1 1.7 1 .4 0 2.2-.3 2.3 0 0 .7.3 2.5 1 1 .5-.9.4-.7.8-.4.2.3.8.2.8.7 0 1.3-.7.5-.7 1.8 0 .5-.2 1.3-.1 1.6 0 .5 1.3-.2 1.7.4h-1c.5.8.6 1 1.3 1.3l.3.1c.7.3.1.4.5 1 .3.4.6.7 1 .7s1 0 1.1.2c.3.2 1 .2 1 .8.2.6.1.9.7 1.1 1 .4 1.6-.2 1.6 1 0 1.3 1.2.8 1.3 2.2 0 .6 4.2-.7 3.2.8-.3.4-.5-.2-.4.7 0 .8 1 2.1 1.6 2.1.7 0 1.1-.4 1.9-.4 0 2.4.5 2 2.6 2 2.7 0 6.1 2.8 6.3 5.2 0 .7.8 2.7 1.2 2.8 2 .4 1.3 3.9 3.6 3.2 1.4-.4 1.8-.9 3 .4l1 1c.3.1 1.2-.3 1.7-.3v1.7c0 1-1 .1-1 1-.2 1.1-1.2 1.8-1 3 .3 1 .7 5.3 1.5 5.6l-40.6 1.8-15.2 29.7 4.7 3.9c0 4.3-2 6.9-2 11 0 1.9-.6 2.6-.6 4.4 0 2-1 2.7-1.8 3.7a70 70 0 01-8.1-7.4c-7.5-10.8-20.1-16.9-30-26.1-4.6-4.3-12.8-6.6-17.8-10.9a13.8 13.8 0 00-6-2.3z" id="CHP"/>
                <path d="M740.8 526.8l1.3 2.3.2 3.3c0 1.6.5.6 1 1.6.2.4-1.5 2.2-.5 3.5.3.4 2.6-.2 3 0 1.6 1-.8 1.5 2.1 2.6 1.3 1 1.6 2.7 3.3 2.8 1.6 0 4 1 3.6 2.5-.5 1.8 2 1.6 2.3 2.3 0 .1.5 4.5-.3 4.9-1.3.7 0 2.2 0 4 .9-1.7 2.4 1.3 2.7-2.5 0-1.4 1.3-.9 1.6-1.5a26 26 0 001.2-4c.3-1.5.6-.8 1.2-1.5.9-.8-.3-1.4 1-2.4.4-.3 1-.5 1.3-1 1.1-1.3 1-3.2-1.2-3.2l-.2-3.2 1-3.7c1.4-.6 1.4.4 1.8-.7.2-.4.8-.2 1-.3.5-.3 1.1-.1 1.8-.2.4 0 0-.7.7-.7.6 0 2.4.8 1.2 1.4-.2.1-1-.3-.7.3.4 1 .5.3 1 1 .3 0 .5.8.6.8.5 0 1-.4 1.6-.4.8 0 .5.7.5 1.4 0 .6.4.9 0 1.4-.4.7 1.4.7 1.6.8v6.3c.5 0 1.4.7 1.4 1.2 0 1.4-.4 1.6 1.2 1.6l2.5-.2c2.4 0 .9 0 2 1.2.1.2.4.1.3.4-.2.3-1.3 2.2-.2 1.9.3 0 1.5-.1 1.6.2 0 .7-.9.7-.4 1 1.2.7.7.7 2.3.7.1-.3.4 0 .5-.5.1-.3.3-.6.2-1 0-.5-.1 0-.2-.4 0-.6.6-1.7 1-2 .3 0 .5 0 .6-.3.2-.3 0-1.8.2-2.3.6 0 2.6 0 2.6-.7 0-1.2.6-1 1.6-1.4 2-.7 3.4.4 4.4-2 .6-1.5-1-2.3 1.4-2.3.8 0-1 .8.2-.6.4-.6 1.5-.6 1.9-1 .8-1 3.1-1.7 3.1-2.7 0-1 0-.9 1.1-1.2.8-.2 1.8 0 1.8-1.2 0-1.4.8-3.8 1.5-1.4.2.6.6 0 .6 1 0 1.5 1.1 1 1.2.4 0-1 0-.7 1-.7s1.2.4 2.1.7c.4.1 1 .2 1.1.5.2.7 0 1.2.3 1.8.5.6 0 1-.1 1.7.3.3.3.7.5.7.5 0 .5 0 .9.4.9.7.4.3 1.4.2 1.3-.2.8 0 1 1 .2 1 .6-.5.6.9 0 1.3 1 .2 1.2 1.4 0 .8-.9 1.3-.4 2 .3.2.3 1 0 1.1-.5.5-1.2.5-.5 1 .2 0 .2.6.2 1-.6.2 0 .8.7.5.4-.2.7-.4 1.6-.4 1.3 0 .9 1 1.7 1 .4 0 2.2-.3 2.3 0 0 .7.3 2.5 1 1 .5-.9.4-.7.8-.4.2.3.8.2.8.7 0 1.3-.7.5-.7 1.8 0 .5-.2 1.3-.1 1.6 0 .5 1.3-.2 1.7.4l11-.2-.2-7-.1-17.7c-2.4-2-6.6-.2-8.5-1.7-2.2-1.8-2.3-.3-4.7-1-1.4-.4-2.3-1.4-3.6-1.4h-3v7.5c-1.7 0-3-.1-4-1.2-.4-.7-3.1-.7-4-.7-1.8 0 0-.9-.8-1.8-.3-.3-1.5 0-1.8-.2-.7-.2-3.6-2.3-4-1.8-.6.5-1 .4-2.1.4-1 0-.4-3.7-1.8-3.9v-7.5h-1c-.7 0-.2 0-.4-.2-.7-.3-1 .6-1.3-.4 0-.6-1.2.4-1.6.4h-.6c-.4 0-2 .2-2-.2l-.4-1.2-1.7.2v-2.9l-2.8-.7v-1.4c-.4.1-.9.4-1.4.8-1.8.7-3.1 1.3-4.6 2.1-1.1.6-1.9.5-2.9 1.4-2 2.1-5 4.6-8 4.7-.8 0-1.4.2-1.3 1.2 0 1.2-.9 4-2.6 2.8-2-1.4 2.3-2.8 1.2-2.8-.9 0-2.3.3-2.4.2-.6-.6-2.5-.7-3.7-.7-2.2 0-6 0-7 1.2-3.5 3.6-10.5 2-13 5.9l-2.3.7c-.7.2-1.3.5-1.8.9z" id="TAB"/>
            </g>
            <g id="g6310" transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,1636.39,215.04306)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Since the user has not said that they are D3, this is probably not a very helpful answer. for them

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thank you for your comment. My assumption is that everybody uses D3, but I'm probably wrong :) Anyway, the notion about z-index in SVG is correct and my answer gives some useful clue in the right direction.

Comment: D3 is great, but maybe not the best choice for someone new.  I know there are already answers on here covering this problem. Trying to find them now.

Comment: I'm trying to find something similar to `raise` in jQuery and don't see anything close...

Comment: After all, it can be done with `.removeChild` and `.insertBefore`